# On a Netbeans Java application, how do I open a new page (not a popup) by clicking a button?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have created a Java app on Netbeans. How can I open a new page by clicking a button, without the page being a popup? I would like it to be like when creating a website with HTML, and pressing a button/link simply redirects to another page.

All of the solutions I read explain how to create a page that pops up.

**Edit and clarification:**

This is the code I am running (the action taken once the button is pressed).

```
private void LoginButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
       displays s = new displays();
       s.setVisible(true);
```

Once the Login Button is pressed, a new JFrame opens. Instead, I want the JFrame with the Login Button to show something different, on the same page (once the person is logged in, in this example).

Comment: From your question it is unclear what you want and what NetBeans' role is. You can explain this by showing us the code you currently have and perhaps one of the solutions that did not work for you.

Comment: I added a clarification to my question.

Comment: With so little code it is hard to be specific, but your button is sitting probably on a JPanel. Inside the actionPerformed() you can change that panel to reflect the new state. Perhaps you can show more code. Also: convention has class names starting with an uppercase letter and method names with a lower case letter, so loginButtonActionPerformed() and Displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This little illustration probably does you want. It has a form with a button. Once it is clicked, a textfield on the panel changes.

```
    public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        jButton1.setText("Click me");
        jLabel1.setText("Not yet clicked");

        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jLabel1.setText("clicked");
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(146, 146, 146)
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(172, 172, 172)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)))
                .addContainerGap(160, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(80, 80, 80)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(78, 78, 78)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(102, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });          
}
```